# my bike pedals but the back tire will not move

Tags: mountain-bike

I have a mountain bike and it was working well.then I started to pedal and the back wheel isn't moving.could someone tell me what it could be?

Comment: A few more details would help. Does the cassette move?

Comment: Does the cassette just spin?  Does it still click when you spin the wheel?  If it is spinning and a freewheel then not a lot you can do.  If you have a freehub it might just be gunked up.  This is a good video on how to service a freehub.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f19BGYc5ysA   It that seems like too much then just take it to a bike shop.

Comment: Is there a chain on the bike?

Comment: There is a chain.

Comment: Does anyone know about how much it would cost to fix it

Comment: Does the chain move when you pedal?

Comment: Are there spokes?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that the hub's freewheel mechanism has broken. Maybe it's fixable with some spare parts or you may need a new freewheel hub body or a new hub altogether. Your LBS will be able to assess the situation.

It looks like this: https://www.google.gr/search?q=mtb+freewheel+hub+body&tbm=isch

Comment: It might be fixable just by cleaning and lubing